# How to Solve the "An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "page" not found in collection "@ngxs/schematics"" in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "page" not found in collection "@ngxs/schematics".

Comment: I am no Ionic expert, but I'm pretty confident that this question would be improved if you added some more details about what you are doing when this exception occurs.

Answer (score 6):

When you switch to `@ngrx/schematics` as default collection which by default extends `@schematics/angular`, you can only uses schematics relevant to angular and ngrx. You have to switch to `@ionic/angular-toolkit` collection as default in order to use ionic schematics.

To use `@ionic/angular-toolkit` as default collection use `ng config cli.defaultCollection @ionic/angular-toolkit`.

You'll have to switch between `@ngrx/schematics` and `@ionic/angular-toolkit` because the CLI doesn't support multiple default collections. there is [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12157) which track that issue. Check it out.